# What is the simplest way to understand difference between binary data and the string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried the below code:

```
buf = new Buffer(10);
len = buf.write("ABCD");
str = "ABCD";
console.log("Octets written : "+  len);
console.log("Buf is    : "+  buf);
```

Here buf, and str both are same right?. I have seen lots of form talking about converting string to binary data. Why it is required to do so?.. Please execuse me for this basic question.

NOTE: My understading is that string is also requires 4 bytes to store "ABCD", and which is stored in the memory as a byte. Please correct me.

Comment: *"My understading is that string is also requires 4 bytes to store "ABCD", and which is stored in the memory as a byte. Please correct me."* Okay: You're wrong. Strings in JavaScript are [UTF-16](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-terms-and-definitions-string-value) (but allowing invalid surrogate pairs), so two bytes are required per character (plus string overhead).

Comment: in that case still str.length provides 4 right?

Comment: Yes, `length` on strings returns the number of *characters* in the string, not the size of the string in bytes.

Comment: if string were used to store single byte for a character, then it is equivalent to buffer right ?

Comment: Otherway is anything that requires single byte to store the value can be treated equival to Buffer ??.

Comment: A string can't be stored in a single byte, AFAIK. It's either 1 character or no characters, so zero or two bytes.